# How to read values from datarows. OleDB

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oledb, dbf

I am reading dbf file through `oledb`. I am getting fieldsname and their types but issue is that i am not getting any value in rows.

My code is as follows:

```
string mySQL = "select * from line75.dbf";  // dbf table name
                OleDbCommand MyQuery = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, yourConnectionHandler);
                OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(MyQuery);

                DA.Fill(YourResultSet);

                for (int i = 0; i < YourResultSet.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    FieldInfo field = new FieldInfo();
                    field.fieldname = YourResultSet.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    field.fieldtype = YourResultSet.Columns[i].DataType.FullName;

                    tableFields.Add(field);
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = YourResultSet;
```

when i view at `datagridview`, then i am getting just `fieldnames` but i am not getting any value.

I have tried many dbf files, but the result is the same.

What i am doing wrong here? I am very confused as i am simply opening connection and trying to get all data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this, it should work

```
        using (OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            var ConnectionString = new StringBuilder("");
            ConnectionString.Append(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;");
            ConnectionString.Append(@"Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x;");
            ConnectionString.Append(@"Data Source=D:\dbf;");
            _connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString.ToString();
            _connection.Open();

            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM line75.dbf;", _connection))
            {
                using (DataSet dsRetrievedData = new DataSet())
                {
                    da.Fill(dsRetrievedData);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dsRetrievedData;
                    dataGridView1.DataMember = dsRetrievedData.Tables[0].TableName;
                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

I tried it by myself

1 I created simple WinForms application

2 Downloaded dbf from this https://www.ibiblio.org/laslave/downloads/

3 Then added component DataGridView to Form

4 Then added this code

```
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                var ConnectionString = new StringBuilder("");
                ConnectionString.Append(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;");
                ConnectionString.Append(@"Extended Properties=dBASE IV;");
                ConnectionString.Append(@"Data Source=c:\temp;");
                _connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString.ToString();
                _connection.Open();

                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SLAVE.DBF", _connection))
                {
                    using (DataSet dsRetrievedData = new DataSet())
                    {
                        da.Fill(dsRetrievedData);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsRetrievedData;
                        dataGridView1.DataMember = dsRetrievedData.Tables[0].TableName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

5 And all works fine
[image]

Comment: btw how to use this? is this a function?

Comment: What do you mean? You can use it as well as the code in your question

Comment: i dont understand this   using (OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection())

Comment: i wanted to ask is this a function or i simply copy paste your code

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx is about OleDBConnection. It's a new connection object. It's the same that in your `yourConnectionHandler` I guess

Comment: And you can copy past it,but change the name of the table and connectionstring

Comment: Proofread your code carefully, all shoud work fine. I've recentely checked it

Comment: i will check my dbf file

Comment: one last thing is it possible to read specific row data like i just want to read row 0 data?

Comment: first column of first row `var zz = dsRetrievedData.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];`

Comment: yes i have got data from dbf. Code is correct there is issue with my dbf file. I have downloaded your dbf and its working correct

Comment: And why didn't you mark my answer as correct? :) It's a long coversation between you and me. If that question is complted, then close it. If you have any additional questions, just create new question. I'm done.